# Post coordinates to Php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send (x,y) coordinates from script HTML code to PHP but it doesn't work:

-**Script code:**

`searchControl.on("results", function (data) {
            results.clearLayers();
            for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng, { draggable: true, title: 'Local' }));
                x = data.results[i].latlng.lng;
                y = data.results[i].latlng.lat;`

**-PHP piece of code to get coordinates:**

```
    <?php 
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=*** dbname=*** user=*** password=***")
    or die('Not connected: ' . pg_last_error());

// Get Parameters

$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
```

Is `$.ajax` the best option? How could it be possible with this?.

Comment: $_GET is an associative array of your url-parameter.

Comment: Should be work this?:
`function inf(x, y){var data = { "x": x, "y": y };
$.ajax({url: "http://localhost/testphp?",data: data,
type: "POST",success: function (e) {alert(e);},
      error: function (er) {
      alert("Error: " + er);
          }
        });`

Comment: If you are using the POST method to send data, it would be accessible through the `$_POST` array in PHP.